# IllegalStateException "No pool annotation"

Tags: jboss, ejb, activemq-classic, jboss6.x, jboss-mdb

Tying to launch my .ear on a Local JBoss 6.1.0 Final with local ActiveMQ. As I'm starting the Jboss. I get:

```
09:56:52,300 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: message-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
09:56:52,304 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:ear=message-service-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT,jar=message-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=MedhjalparService,service=EJB3
09:56:52,304 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
09:56:52,304 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel]   and demands:
09:56:52,304 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel]     jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService; Required: Described
09:56:52,304 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel]     jboss-switchboard:appName=message-service-ear-1,module=message-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT,name=MedhjalparService; Required: Create
09:56:52,304 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
09:56:52,305 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel]     jndi:null
09:56:52,305 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel]     Class:javax.jms.MessageListener
09:56:52,307 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:ear=message-service-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT,jar=message-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=MedhjalparService,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: message-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
09:56:52,347 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.j2ee:ear=message-service-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT,jar=message-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=MedhjalparService,service=EJB3 state=Create: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No pool annotation
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.initializePool(EJBContainer.java:1325) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.initializePool(MessagingContainer.java:357) [:1.7.21]
```

And heres the code:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageMDBSample", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/MyQueue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")}


public class ExampleMDBean implements MessageListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void onMessage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong activeMQ-rar.rar. the one int deployment had a versionnumber in the filename and the configuration I was using did not..